# Why does Amazon Kindle cache books in its AppData folder on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, kindle

I have Amazon Kindle installed on Windows 7.
When I open a file, Kindle makes a copy of it at,

```
C:\Users\<NAME>\Documents\Kindle\
```

The folder above can be set at `Tools -> Options... -> Content`
Why does it do that? How can I disable this local-content-caching setting altogether and avoid having two copies of every book?

Answer (score 0):

It's so you can re-sync at any time afterwards, even if you lose the device & have to get a new one, your purchases are saved locally.

Books are tiny, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: 'the device' is not the PC, it's 'the kindle'

Comment: What's your point? ... if you lose the kindle & buy another, you have a restore to work from. It's like iTunes, the phone/pad/pod is not the master controller, the compy is.

Comment: Extra info - if the kindle app is auto-copying to a non-casual-user space, then the original can be discarded [same as iTunes etc]

Comment: Except it's not a "non-standard" location

Comment: I didn't say 'non-standard' I said 'non-casual-user' - an area deliberately hidden from the less-confident user.

Comment: ok. but how to disable this behavior? I don't have much hard-drive space and I don't want to migrate all my docs to Kindle's special folder. I want to be able to maintain my own directory structure (containing the docs) that I have in place elsewhere on the drive.

Comment: Just throw out the original once it's 'organised' itself. I don't use Kindle, for many reasons, but iTunes has a similar behaviour - though with an option to not organise automatically. Maybe Kindle has something similar...